# How to create CommonsMultipartFile object given only a file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, apache-commons

I have a junit test method that takes a CommonsMultipartFile object as a parameter.

I'm trying to create a FileItem object so I can pass it to the constructor,

```
CommonsMultipartFile(org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem fileItem)
```

To do that, I'm trying to create the FileItem object using the DiskFileItem constructor,

```
DiskFileItem(java.lang.String fieldName, java.lang.String contentType, boolean isFormField, java.lang.String fileName, int sizeThreshold, java.io.File repository)
```

but I'm not sure how to pass any of those parameters.

I have all of this working in a Spring 3 MVC controller, but to do my junit tests, I need to pass a method two objects. One is the UploadItem object which looks like the following,

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

public class UploadItem {
 private String fileName;
 private String filePath;
 private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;

 public String getFileName() {
  return fileName;
 }

 public void setFileName(String fileName) {
  this.fileName = fileName;
 }

 public String getFilePath() {
  return filePath;
 }

 public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
  this.filePath = filePath;
 }

 public CommonsMultipartFile getFileData() {
  return fileData;
 }

 public void setFileData(CommonsMultipartFile fileData) {
  this.fileData = fileData;
 }
}
```

The setFileData() method requires the CommonsMultipartFile object which I'm trying to create just given a file in my src/test/resources directory.

Would anyone know how I can take a file, create a FileItem object and pass that to the CommonsMultipartFile object constructor?

Thanks. If anything is unclear, please let me know - I'm not that familiar with Spring MVC file uploads.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the more common interface [`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html). instead of
`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile` in your Command (UploadItem). (CommonsMultipartFile is a 1:1 implementation of the Interface).

Now you can create an instance of `CommonsMultipartFile` with the mock class [`org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html). (which is element of `spring-test.jar`).

Then the creation of an MultipartFile in the tests is only one statement, without any cast:

```
MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
       "test.txt",                //filename
       "Hallo World".getBytes()); //content
```

Answer (score -2):

How is this of any help? you don't set the file on the request, it should be used like this:

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = getMockCommonsMultipartFile(BULK_CSV);
MockMultipartHttpServletRequest request = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();
request.addFile(multipartFile);
CommonsMultipartFile commonsMultipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) request.getFile(BULK_CSV);
```

I am using a method with the argument `CommonsMultipartFile`, otherwise I could have used `MockMultipartFile` directly.

```
 private MultipartFile getMockCommonsMultipartFile(String name, String path) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(name, name, "", is);
        return multipartFile;
    }
```